# The opposite of this function

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, ChatUser> _users = new Dictionary<string, ChatUser>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
private static readonly Dictionary<string, ChatRoom> _rooms = new Dictionary<string, ChatRoom>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

public IEnumerable<ChatUser> GetUsersInRoom(string room)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(room))
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<ChatUser>();
    }

    var results = from name in _rooms[room].Users
                           select _users[name];

    return results;
}
```

How do I get people who are *not* in the provided room? :-/

Comment: I've tried to incorporate some inverse function, but I can not seem to get it to work.

Comment: For instance? Code examples would help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var usersNotInRoom = _users.Values.Except(GetUsersInRoom("ROOM"));
```